# Dynamic Columns

Tags: reporting-services

Here's my problem.  I am passing in a parameter let say it's called `ShapesSelected`.
`ShapeSelected = ",Square, Triangle, Circle,"`.
The problem is `ShapeSelected` could be any of the the shapes so it is never `static`.

Base on this parameter I want to add 3 column to the right of a table in the report.  Is this possible?  I've starting coding it in `Custom Code` in Report Properties but I am stuck as in how to add the column.

```
Public Function GetReportShapes( ByVal ShapesSelected As String )                 
    Dim Shapes() As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Entities = Split(ShapesSelected ,", ")

    For i = 0 To UBound ( Shapes)
             Select case Shapes(i)
               case "Square": 'add Square Column here
                    case "Rectangle": add Rectange Column here  
               case "Triangle": add Triangle Column here
        End Select  
    Next i

End Function
```

Thus rendering the columns like this:

```
Square  Triangle   Circle
```

Answer (score 1):

Add all the columns you need and use the hidden or visible property (I forget which) with vb expressions to turn them on and off.